# Preparing dataset

Tags: pandas, csv, dataset

I have a dataset as a "csv" file and it has 960 rows and 52 columns. I want to delete the first 160 rows and then from the remaining data I want to select 480 random rows and save them as a new csv file. How can I do that? I am new to python and I am not able to do everything at once. Help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you managed to read your CSV file into a pandas dataframe yet?

Comment: Can you add some data sample of csv?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use parameter `skiprows` for remove first `160` rows and then [`sample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sample.html) for random rows:

```
df = pd.read_csv('file', skiprows=range(1, 161)).sample(480)

df.to_csv('out.csv', index=False)
```